# Ajax asynchronous request not responding when file download in progress

Tags: ajax, file, asynchronous, download

I have a link that when clicked requests **download.php** and that file will post headers and begin a file download. I also have a function called **download_count** that executes (via onclick)  when the link is clicked and starts an AJAX request. The AJAX request executes a file called fetch.php.

```
<a href="https://site.com/download.php?id=1" onclick="download_count();">Click to Download</a>
```

If the AJAX request is asynchronous, fetch.php never responds (Firebug indicates that it is loading). The Save File dialog pops up and the file can be downloaded but without the extra stuff that AJAX call is supposed to do.

Here are the headers that download.php sends:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blah.rar");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

If the AJAX request is synchronous, fetch.php returns a result and all is well. My javascript is able use the results returned by fetch.php to make some changes to the page HTML before the Save File dialog pops up.

I'm guessing my problem has something to do with the fact that download.php sends some headers to start a file download while download_count() is trying to do an AJAX request. I don't really understand the reason why this is a problem.

Could someone please clarify why synchronous AJAX works in this case and asynchronous doesn't? Is there a way to get the asynchronous call working while still allowing the file to be downloaded by requesting download.php?

Answer (score 1):

Downloading a file navigates the browser away from the current page. Thus the browser will cancel any and all active AJAX connections. The solution is to put your file download in the success block of your AJAX call. That way it won't have to be synchronous, but your AJAX call will be guaranteed to complete.

The file download in the success block can look something like this:

```
function download_count(url) {

  $.ajax({
     url: "fetch.php",
     success: function() {
       window.location = url;
     }
  });

  return false;
}
```

The `return false` will block the hyperlink. Then your HTML will be:

```
<a href="https://site.com/download.php?id=1" onclick="return download_count(this.href);">Click to Download</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Makes sense but I don't understand why the synchronous call works... is it because the AJAX request holds things up and finishes BEFORE the download.php can direct the browser away from the current page?

Comment: Correct. When you have a synchronous request, the browser waits until the connection returns. Since the URL will not navigate until the onclick handler is done (in case you want to cancel it by returning false) the AJAX completes before the href url is activated.

Comment: Thanks again! Just thinking about what you said and it seems that putting the file download in the success block is essentially the same thing as a synchronous AJAX call because the download doesn't occur until the AJAX is done.

Comment: It's almost the same. The primary difference is that you won't lock the user's browser. Remember, the browser is completely locked until the Javascript completes!

Comment: But I guess if it's asynchronous other things on the page can happen while waiting for the request to complete.

Comment: You are most welcome! Don't forget to click "answered" if I solved your problem so that others know it was the right solution.

Comment: Not quite there yet. I tried your sample code and it does initiate the download but there is no Save As dialog box. The AJAX file download request in the success function doesn't seem to be correctly directing to the browser window. I assumed whatever.php should be the download.php link... Still playing around...

Comment: Nope, cannot get the Save As dialog box to pop up. Is it possible that window.location = url is being called too late, i.e. after the download.php request is made?

Comment: Make sure whatever.php points to your Ajax URL and not the download link. The window.location is what does the download. Also try checking the browser Javascript console to see if there were any errors. Finally, make sure that the AJAX call is in your style. That's jQuery code in my example. If you are still having problems, please post your previously working download_count function in an edit and I'll adjust my answer to match.

Comment: OK, got it all working I think. My fault... not yours!